# php session cart does not handle sizes

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I have the following php code that add items to a session based shopping cart. It works fine when using items that don't come in a variation like size for example. The products consist of various clothes. Some come in different sizes and some not. One product can be a t-shirt that come in different sizes and another can be a cap that just is available in one size. I want to be able to add the t-shirt to the cart in different sizes. As it is now it only add to the session based cart if it not present. If present it will update the qty.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
/*include("session.php");   */
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{

  if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
  {

      $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"],"item_id");
      if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
      {
         $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
         $item_array = array(
            'item_id'       => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_description'     => $_POST["hidden_description"],
            'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_qty'      => $_POST["hidden_qty"],
            'itm_size'      => $_POST["select-size-1"],
            'itm_color'     => $_POST["product-1-color"]
         );
         $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] =  $item_array;
      }
      else
      {
            // article exsits, update or remove
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
                    if ($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"] and ($values["itm_size"] != $_GET["select-size-1"]))
                    {
                        // check it item id is the same but color differs, if so add to session array
                        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                        $item_array = array(
                        'item_id'       => $_GET["id"],
                        'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                        'item_description'     => $_POST["hidden_description"],
                        'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                        'item_qty'      => $_POST["hidden_qty"],
                        'itm_size'      => $_POST["select-size-1"],
                        'itm_color'     => $_POST["product-1-color"]
                        );
                        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] =  $item_array;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    // Orginal kod
                    if ($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
                    {
                        // Om man anger 0 som antal ska artikel tas bort
                        if ($_POST["hidden_qty"] == "")
                        {
                            unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // update qty
                            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$keys]['item_qty'] += $_POST["hidden_qty"];
                        }
                    }
                    }




            }


      }
  }
  else
  {
      //echo '<script>alert("session is set")</script>';
      $item_array = array(
        'item_id'       => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'item_description'     => $_POST["hidden_description"],
        'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_qty'      => $_POST["hidden_qty"],
        'itm_size'      => $_POST["select-size-1"],
        'itm_color'     => $_POST["product-1-color"]
      );
      $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] =  $item_array;
  }
}
?>
```

So the qty should update based on ID on Size...

UPDATE: I have added what I thought would help considering handling sizes also. It do not work, if I add a t-shirt with Size XL it add it as it should, but when I add another t-shirt with size XL it does not change the qty but 2 more t-shirts with the same size?

Comment: _“I want to be able to add the t-shirt to the cart in different sizes.”_ - well then you will need to check if a record for the specific _combination_ of product ID and size exists already - right now, you are checking the product ID only.

Comment: I've updated the code with what I thought would work, but it does not. Instead it add one extra item if adding the same product and size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explain by 04FS, you doesn't check the size but only the product ID.

[EDIT]

Ok, let's simplify and clarify the all code... Carrefull to this line: `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$index]['item_qty']++;`, I'm not sure it's exactly what you want.

```
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{

    $index = false;

    if(!isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
        $index = false;
    }
    else {

        foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {

            if($value["item_id"] == $_REQUEST["id"] && $value['itm_size'] == $_POST['select-size-1']) {
                $index = $key;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    if($index !== false) {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$index]['item_qty']++;
    }
    else {
        // create new entry in the session shopping_cart
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = array(
                                            'item_id'       => $_REQUEST["id"],
                                            'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                                            'item_description'     => $_POST["hidden_description"],
                                            'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                                            'item_qty'      => $_POST["hidden_qty"],
                                            'itm_size'      => $_POST["select-size-1"],
                                            'itm_color'     => $_POST["product-1-color"]
                                         );
    }

}
```

[/EDIT]

Feel free to ask if you need help with that.

Comment: Hi @Xenofexs. I tried your code which update the qty if the same sixe is present but as it is now one extra item with the same size is added to the array...?

Comment: I've reproduce your code and it's work as espected ... Do you have exactly the same size name ?

Comment: Yes I do. for me it works like this (which is not good). Add one t-shirt size S = works fine, add another t-shirt size S = works as expected meaning there are now one item in array (2 t-shirt size S). Then I add the same t-shirt size XL = works as expected. But if I add the t-shirt once more with size XL the cart now contain the following rows.... Row 1. 2 T-Shirts Size S, Row 2. 2 t-shirt Size XL, Row 3. 1 t-shirt size XL. As you see the Row 3 should not be there and I dont know why its there.....?

Comment: True. Look at the change in my response.

Comment: Thanks, it now works better. But if you add an item with qty 0 it still increment that items qty..

Comment: Yep, I'm help you, not doing the all job for you ;). You know how to do that, you've already do this before ;)